# consulta sql via JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

como posso realizar uma consulta dinâmica no banco de dados usando o js?

```
                <select" name="secao">
                    <option value="">SEÇÃO</option>
                </select>


                <select" name="subsecao">
                    <option value="">SUBSEÇÃO</option>
                </select>
```

preciso criar um novo select para subseções, mas as subseções vão aparecer de acordo com a seção
por isso preicso que as subseções pareçam de acordo com as seções

no meu banco de dados tenho as colunas de seção e subseção, eu programo em php, más não vejo como fazer em php,
fico grato se alguém com conhecimento em js puder ajudar.

Comment: Você teria que usar [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX), ou seja, cada vez que o valor do seu select mudar, dispara uma requisição para o backend e daí exibe no outro select a resposta da requisição.

Comment: como posso faze isso?

Comment: Vou adicionar um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que usar [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) para falar com o backend. Cada vez que o valor do seu select mudar, dispara uma requisição para o backend e daí exibe no outro select a resposta da requisição.

- Evento sendo disparado cada vez que seu select mudar

  ```
  let selectSecao = document.querySelector('#seu-select')
  let selectSubSecao = document.querySelector('#seu-outro-select')

  selectSecao.onchange = function(e) { // toda vez que o select mudar, essa função será chamada

  let valorSecao = e.target.value // pega o valor atual do select name="secao"

  // enviar requisição para o backend
  fetch(`seu-backend.php?secao=${valorSecao}`)
     .then(response => response.text()) // aqui voce diz que vai recuperar um texto do backend, pode ser json tbm
     .then(subsecao => {
        selectSubSecao.innerHTML = subsecao // aqui você vai botar no html do seu select, o que o seu backend retornar
     })
  }
  ```

---

- Recupera o valor passado para o backend, e pode ser utilizado como filtro no banco

  ```
  $valorSecao = $_GET['secao']; // recupera o valor secao passado na requisição do front end

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE secao"; // ... aqui você faz a sua consulta sql, cuidado com sql injection!!

  $subsecaoBd = []; // digamos que esse são seus dados do banco, agora voce pode montar o html do seu select
  $html = '';

  foreach($subsecaoBd as $sub) {
     $html.= "<option value='{$sub['id']}'>{$sub['nome']}</option>"; // monta o select com os dados do bd
  }

  echo $html;
  exit(); // acaba o arquivo, pois só queremos retornar o html que vai preencher o select
  ```

Assim, você vai conseguir filtrar o valor seção e printar ele no seu outro select, que precisa ser filtrado =D

Comment: não consegui retomar esses dados, tem como falar contigo?

Comment: Tem sim, meu linkedin ta no perfil.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, consegui concluir, nunca havia usado ajax antes

Comment: Showw, só não esquece de marcar a pergunta como resposta aceita, pra ajudar quem também tiver essa dúvida.

Answer (score -3):

Para acessar o banco de dados você precisa de uma API, está usando javascript, fica mais facíl usar nodeJs. Para consumir a api use o fetch ou axios.

fica mais facil você usar algum framework como react ou vue, senão o html dinámico.

Comment: Ele disse que usa php.